# I appreciate her regularly/regularity in her studies

Tags: adverbs, nouns, exam-questions

> I appreciate her **regularly/regularity** in her studies.

The given answer is **regularity.**

**Regularity** is a noun, and **regularly** is an adverb.

Is **regularity** used since a noun should come after a possessive adjective(her)?

Is adverb **regularly** can only be used before the main verb?

> *i.e.,* I **regularly** appreciate her in her studies.

Comment: The two words would give the sentence a different meaning. I don't think that "I appreciate her regularly" is the intended meaning, but that the speaker appreciates the fact that she _studies regularly_.

Comment: @KateBunting but without context, "regularly" can be correct too. Is such type of questions asked in your country? Asking because these type of questions are asked in exam in India.

Comment: It can be _grammatically_ correct, but 'I appreciate her regularly' sounds very odd. Appreciation is generally an ongoing feeling, not something you do at regular intervals. It's many decades since I took any English exams, but I expect that 'word choice' questions are sometimes included.

Comment: @KateBunting yes it too struct me odd. I think my non native ear and tongue got defected for good :-D but above everything I guess here the best thing to ask was to identify the best answer from the alternatives, not the correct answer. My opinion, of course.

Comment: My take there which makes the question better is that, while "I appreciate her regularly" can be correct "I appreciate her regularly *in her studies*" doesn't make sense - what does appreciating a person in her studies even mean? That you appreciate the person while she's a student?

Comment: Yes that is a good point too.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is in the meaning of the phrases when you change an adverb for a noun.

When you say "I appreciate her regularity in her studies" you are saying that you appreciate the regularity, that is, the verb applies to the noun. You are appreciating how regular her studies are.

When you say "I appreciate her regularly in her studies" appreciate would apply to the first "her" and not to "her studies". So you are saying that you appreciate her at constant intervals, instead of how regular she is in her studies. In addition, the "in her studies" part of the phrase is no longer working, even if you switch the place of the adverb, because "appreciating X in Y" doesn't really exist, at least not in this sense of appreciate.

To use an adverb and retain the meaning you'd need to change the construction of the phrase, for example: "I appreciate how regularly she studies" (you are not appreciating "her", but "how regularly")